# Duplicate link box has no link

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

This question:
[Drop the last item with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166493/drop-the-last-item-with-linq)

has a strange looking duplicate box... which does not specify what the duplicate is:

[image]

It does have the "possible duplicate..." link but that you can see in the markdown so doesn't appear to be related to the box.